# Adding custom domain to google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am a newbie to google compute engine, I looked at various tutorials and could add a custom domain to app engine. I added a sub domain as advised in the tutorial http://demo.appostrophi.com/ [http://demo.appostrophi.com/][1]. I want my URL to be www.appostrophi.com/ but it's showing a blank screen. What could I have possibly done wrong.
I have added the resource names as suggested by google with my domain registrar.
Please advice.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS registration appears incorrect (or didn't yet have time to propagate properly):

> Firefox can’t find the server at www.appostrophi.com.

and

> Firefox can’t find the server at appostrophi.com.

The document you mentioned is not the proper procedure to register a domain and/or a subdomain to a GAE app. See [Adding a custom domain for your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application).

Comment: thanks, I had to make some adjustments in Cloud DNS and it worked. I am trying to setup an FTP to connect to the VM and make changes to my web pages, any help is always solicited.